# reachability of a host vs. the reachability of a host

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

Source: [UNIX System Administration—A Beginner's Guide by Steve Maxwell (2002)](https://books.google.com/books/about/UNIX_System_Administration_A_Beginner_s.html?id=tIAhAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Example:

> This is useful so that the user can quickly determine **reachability of a host** without wasting additional time or network bandwidth.

If I had to write that passage, I'd personally use the article: *the reachability of a host*. It just sounds better to me that way. I think, that's because we're dealing with something specific here, but what are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, "the" helps a lot. But if I were to write the sentence, I would write instead "whether the host can be reached".  I'm not crazy about "reachability", since it's not really a word in the standard dictionary.

Let me guess, this is related to the "ping" function?

Comment: Yes, it's talking about the ping command-line utility. I wouldn't call a function though.

Comment: @CookieMonster I guess it depends on what you think a "function" is.  In strict programming terms "ping" is a kind of a function, but you're right that it's better described as a "utility" because it has so many input options.  But if you ask a different CS person you might get a different answer.

Comment: Well, as I said "ping" is a command-line utility. It has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @CookieMonster  Ah, well, I think you need to expand what you think of as a "program".  Ping was *written* by [Mike Muuss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Muuss) in 1983 and works so well that it's been included in almost every OS since.  It is a thousand lines of programming code, although I'm not sure which language it was originally written in.